# Draggable text Portion inside Text Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I am making a game where users can drag some portion - which is highligted with RED in the image - of String while not hurting rest of the String. To specify which text can be draggable, I encoded draggable portion in this format: x{String}x. And I decoded it in _constructGame function. I expected a well-organized String but it turns out it didn't happen. I encountered with a logical error, rather than a system error. But I can't just figure out. I tried making research but they are irrelevant with my issue.

To reach my goal, I also used a list of widget that goes like fixed text, draggable portion, fixed text, ...

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:schoolproject/GameTextList.dart';

class GameRoute extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _GameRouteState();
  
}

class _GameRouteState extends State<GameRoute>{

  // Random().nextInt(GameTextList.texts.length)
  String gameText = GameTextList.texts[0];

  Draggable _createDraggableText(String text) {
    return Draggable<String>(
      data: text,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
      ),
      feedback: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
      ),
      childWhenDragging: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Precondition: There must be at least one draggable
  List<Widget> _constructGame(String mes) {
    List<Widget> widgets = <Widget>[];

    // Decode the message
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i != mes.length - 1) {
      if (mes[i] == "x" && mes[i + 1] == "{") {
        var last = mes.indexOf("}x", i);
        widgets.add(Text(mes.substring(j, i))); // Bugün hava çok
        widgets.add(_createDraggableText(mes.substring(i + 2, last))); // soğuktu
        j = last + 2;
      }
      i++;
    }
    // add the remaining part of the text
    widgets.add(Text(mes.substring(j, mes.length)));
    return widgets;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Egzersiz")),
      body: Wrap(
        children: _constructGame(gameText),
      )
      );
  }

}
```

---

```
class GameTextList {
    static List<String> texts = [
      "Bugün hava çok x{soğuktuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu}x. Fakat üstümüze mont giymeyi x{unuttuk}x. Şu an yağmur x{yağıyor}x. Son zamanlarda"
          " hava düzensiz olabileceğinden tedbirli olmak x{gerekecekmiş}x.",

      "Planktonların varlığı ekosistem için x{mühimdir}x hatta onlar x{olmasaydı}x  Dünyadaki canlıların bir çoğu yok "
          "x{olurdu}x. Nitekim bu canlılar atmosferdeki oksijenin %50'sini x{oluştururlar}x. Yine de insanlar bilinçsizce"
          " denize atık bırakmaya devam x{ederse}x solunulacak bir x{kalmayacak}x.",

      "Uranyumun keşfedildiği tarih x{1789'dur}x.",

      """
Yapma x{ne olursun}x, bırak o yerimi x{doldursun}x. Bana ihtiyacın x{olursa}x sarıl ona, elbet x{unutursun}x.x{Girmişşe}x kalbine bambaşka biri...""",

    ];
}
```

[image: abc]

[image: abc2]

[image: abc3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after analyse your code, I made some changes in `_constructGame` in your method now its working. i simply debug and identify that you need add only one word at time in widgets list just like you do for extract `x{Draggable Word}x`.so i add code for normal string & commented old lines for the same.

**Added code:**

```
final noramlStringArray = normalString.split(" ");
    noramlStringArray.asMap().forEach((index, word) {
    if (index != (noramlStringArray.length - 1)) {
      widgets.add(Text("$word ")); // add word with trailing space 
    } else {
      widgets.add(Text(word)); // add last word without space 
    }
});
```

Added `String extension` for remove extra white spaces if string contains double or more spaces which replace with single white space.

```
extension on String {
  String removeExtraWhiteSpace() {
    return replaceAll(RegExp("[ \t\r\f]"), " ");
  }
}
```

used **removeExtraWhiteSpace()** extension in below line.

> _constructGame(gameText.removeExtraWhiteSpace())

replace your `_constructGame` method with below code.

```
 // Precondition: There must be at least one draggable
List<Widget> _constructGame(String mes) {
    List<Widget> widgets = <Widget>[];
    
    try {
      // Decode the message
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      while (i != mes.length - 1) {
        if (mes[i] == "x" && mes[i + 1] == "{") {
          var last = mes.indexOf("}x", i);
    
          final normalString = mes.substring(j, i);
          final noramlStringArray = normalString.split(" ");
          noramlStringArray.asMap().forEach((index, word) {
            if (index != (noramlStringArray.length - 1)) {
              widgets.add(Text("$word ")); // add word with trailing space 
            } else {
              widgets.add(Text(word)); // add last word without space 
            }
          });
    
          //widgets.add(Text(mes.substring(j, i))); // Bugün hava çok
    
          widgets
              .add(_createDraggableText(mes.substring(i + 2, last))); // soğuktu
          j = last + 2;
        }
        i++;
      }
      // add the remaining part of the text
      //widgets.add(Text(mes.substring(j, mes.length)));
      final normalString = mes.substring(j, mes.length);
    
      final noramlStringArray = normalString.split(" ");
      noramlStringArray.asMap().forEach((index, word) {
        if (index != (noramlStringArray.length - 1)) {
          widgets.add(Text("$word "));
        } else {
          widgets.add(Text(word));
        }
      });
      return widgets;
    } catch (ex) {
      debugPrint("Error: $ex");
      return widgets;
    }
}
```

if your word will not set in remain width then only it will set in newline automatically.

[image]

Comment: It's working well. But I also want to include new lines. Whereas, your removeExtraWhite space functions deletes them. For example, try this sample text: 
"Yapma x{ne olursun}x, bırak o yerimi x{doldursun}x.\n Bana ihtiyacın x{olursa}x sarıl ona,\n elbet x{unutursun}x.\n x{Girmişşe}xkalbine bambaşka biri...",

Comment: just remove \n from string extension regex and check.

Comment: No, I tried that, still not working, text looks messy.

Comment: replace old string extension REGX with this return replaceAll(RegExp("[ \t\r\f]"), " ");

Comment: answer updated with screenshot checkout now.

Comment: So, is there any possible way to manually set new line?

Comment: not getting you can you explain in detail?

Comment: You said that "if your word will not set in remain width then only it will set in newline automatically.". I prefer to set new line manually, NOT automatically. I will add a screenshot to this post to show the desired output.

Comment: I edited the post with screenshot, please check it out

Comment: yes because of different device width & font size pixel for that device your text will display differently so if you add manually add new line then some device which contain space still force new line added which look much ugly better its will handle more responsive way so just like normal text widget behaviour if text fit in space it will set otherwise automatically set in new lines.

Comment: I see. That is very unlucky for me :( But If I find a way, I will update my post. Thank you.

Comment: if for your sentence not much large then you can but i suggest current one logic is better. because now we removed \n from regx so, suppose if your array 0 element contains large text and \n  require for next element you can also added it via \n forcefully too. you can handle text responsive & forceful new line too.

Comment: grate!. happy coding.