# why setState not working for List of widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter I try to experiment with List of Widget . I try to change state inside the list of widget i.e. initialized in `initState` . I create sample example to what I want to achieve.

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({super.key});

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  bool isChanged = false;
  List<Widget> simpleWidget = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    simpleWidget = [_someComplexWidget(), _someComplexWidget()];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:const Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: simpleWidget,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isChanged = !isChanged;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text("Click"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _someComplexWidget() {
    return Text(
        "Hello",
        style: TextStyle(color: isChanged ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
      );
  }
}
```

I also try with keys but it did not work in this sample code. [When to Use Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers)

What is the reason behind not working this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your simpleWidget is created at initState & it will not change on rebuild.

You should add `[_someComplexWidget(), _someComplexWidget()]` under build for it to change dynamically based on the current state.

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({super.key});

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  bool isChanged = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [_someComplexWidget(), _someComplexWidget()], // HERE
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isChanged = !isChanged;
                  });
                  print(isChanged);
                },
                child: const Text("Click"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _someComplexWidget() {
    return Text(
      "Hello",
      style: TextStyle(color: isChanged ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In  this question [_constructGame() funcion is used to create different types of widget in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041649/draggable-text-portion-inside-text-widget-in-flutter) When we use `_constructGame() OR  _someComplexWidget()` directlly into the build method then complete complex calculation execute every time when setState is called. I am only want to change the simple state after firstbuild.

Comment: Most of the time it does not matter as the build is fast. However, you can always optimize by separate your widget into multiple StatefulWidget/StatelessWidget to prevent unnecessary rebuild.